# React Router V4 - How to only have params?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have couple of components. When a param is in path one will be in active mode and rest will be in inactive mode and show a message.

- All components are present on page. One is active, the rest are inactive but visible.
- Components need to read url params.

If I use path then at each moment, I can show only one component. The first solution that comes to mind is having no path but only have route params. I need to read route params on app.js to show active/deactive component also read the same params in the child components inside app.js

When we don't have any path to match: 
How can I read route params in app.js?
How can I pass route params to child components?

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import Spinner from './components/shared/Spinner';
import { RouteComponentProps, Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const Compoent1 = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'Compoent1' */  './components/Compoent1/Compoent1'));
const Compoent2 = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'Compoent2' */  './components/Compoent2/Compoent2'));
const Compoent3 = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'Compoent3' */  './components/Compoent3/Compoent3'));

export default class App extends React.Component {


    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <Suspense>
                    <Compoent1 routeProps={routeProps}/>
                </Suspense>

                <Suspense>
                    <Compoent2 routeProps={routeProps}/>
                </Suspense>

                <Suspense>
                    <Compoent3 routeProps={routeProps}/>
                </Suspense>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Component1:

```
import React, { MouseEvent } from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface IProps {
    routeProps: RouteComponentProps;
    onUpdate: any;
}

export default function ProductSelector(props: IProps) {

    const test = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        props.onUpdate('test');
    };

    return(
        <button onClick={test}>Next</button>
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. You can have access to URL params regardless route. Maybe you have some code to show?

Comment: @vicodin - Added code... I need to read routeProps in the page also pass it to Component1, Component2 and Component3

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not wrapping your components with `<Router>` you should to wrap them individually with `withRouter`. You can explore withRouter API in the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter).

Basically in your component files you need to import withRouter:

**./components/Compoent1/Compoent1**

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
```

and wrap component's export with it.

```
export default withRouter(Compoent1)
```

This will allow `Compoent1` to access all router props.

Answer (score 0):

In App.js component make a function which you will pass as props to the all child components to update state with the url params:

App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

state = {
  urlParams: []
}


getUrlParamsFromChild = (urlParams) => {
  this.setState({ urlParams: urlParams })
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <Suspense>
                <Compoent1 routeProps={routeProps} getUrlParams={this.getUrlParamsFromChild) />
            </Suspense>

            <Suspense>
                <Compoent2 routeProps={routeProps} getUrlParams={this.getUrlParamsFromChild) />
            </Suspense>

            <Suspense>
                <Compoent3 routeProps={routeProps} getUrlParams={this.getUrlParamsFromChild)/>
            </Suspense>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Child Components:

Make your child components to be class based.

```
componentDidMount() {
  // get params from route
  const urlParams = this.props.match.params

// call function from props to update state from parent, with new child params
  this.props.getUrlParams(urlParams)
}
```